# maxminddb-rust, get value of country for certain language

Tags: rust

I decided to start learning Rust, I haven't finished their book yet but I am trying to build and run other projects so I can learn from the source code. I am now interested in maxmind-rust crate and specifically I want to retrieve country, city and asn values from the .mmdb file.

I tried to convert struct `maxmind::geoip2::Country` to string and use json crate but resulted in errors that I couldn't fix myself.

The code used:

```rust
use maxminddb::geoip2;

use std::net::IpAddr;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main()
{
    let mmdb_file = maxminddb::Reader::open("C:\\path\\to\\GeoLite2-City.mmdb").unwrap();
    let ip_addr: IpAddr = FromStr::from_str("8.8.8.8").unwrap();
    let geoip2_country: geoip2::Country = mmdb_file.lookup(ip_addr).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", geoip2_country);
}
```

The output is:

```
Country
{
    continent: Some(Continent
    {
        code: Some("NA"),
        geoname_id: Some(6255149),
        names: Some(
        {
            "de": "Nordamerika",
            "en": "North America",
            "es": "Norteam?rica",
            "fr": "Am?rique du Nord",
            "ja": "?????",
            "pt-BR": "Am?rica do Norte",
            "ru": "???????? ???????",
            "zh-CN": "???"
        })
    }),
    country: Some(Country
    {
        geoname_id: Some(6252001),
        iso_code: Some("US"),
        names: Some(
        {
            "de": "USA",
            "en": "United States",
            "es": "Estados Unidos",
            "fr": "?tats-Unis",
            "ja": "???????",
            "pt-BR": "Estados Unidos",
            "ru": "???",
            "zh-CN": "??"
        })
    }),
    registered_country: Some(Country
    {
        geoname_id: Some(6252001),
        iso_code: Some("US"),
        names: Some(
        {
            "de": "USA",
            "en": "United States",
            "es": "Estados Unidos",
            "fr": "?tats-Unis",
            "ja": "???????",
            "pt-BR": "Estados Unidos",
            "ru": "???",
            "zh-CN": "??"
        })
    }),
    represented_country: None,
    traits: None
}
```

which is the maxminddb::geoip2::Country struct (http://oschwald.github.io/maxminddb-rust/maxminddb/geoip2/struct.Country.html)

Changing the last line of code to

```rust
println!("{:?}", geoip2_country.country);
```

outputs only the `country` field:

```
country: Some(Country
{
    geoname_id: Some(6252001),
    iso_code: Some("US"),
    names: Some(
    {
        "de": "USA",
        "en": "United States",
        "es": "Estados Unidos",
        "fr": "?tats-Unis",
        "ja": "???????",
        "pt-BR": "Estados Unidos",
        "ru": "???",
        "zh-CN": "??"
    })
}),
```

But looking at the structure of maxminddb::geoip2::model::Country (http://oschwald.github.io/maxminddb-rust/maxminddb/geoip2/model/struct.Country.html), I am very confused as to how I can retrieve from this struct and its pair (language_code, country_name) if I wanted to get the name of country for "en" key.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at how the tests are written and it will give you some idea how to extract the information you are looking for:

https://github.com/oschwald/maxminddb-rust/blob/master/src/maxminddb/reader_test.rs

(*actually, after looking at the tests I didn't find any example extracting what you are looking for*)

That should return what you expect:

```
let country_name = geoip2_country.country
                    .and_then(|cy| cy.names)
                    .and_then(|n| n.get("en")
                    .map(String::from));
```